# Rails Asset Pipeline, SCSS, and Z-Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, z-index

I have a .scss stylesheet that is being processed through the Rails Asset Pipeline. The code is as follows:

```
.new-email {
  .ui.dropdown {
    z-index: 101 !important;
  }
}
```

When I run this in development, it get compiled to :

```
.new-email .ui.dropdown {
  z-index: 101 !important;
}
```

However, when I deploy to our production environment with

```
rake assets:precompile
```

It compiles to

```
.new-email .ui.dropdown{z-index:2!important}
```

What's going on? Is there a compass setting that I don't know about or something is SASS or the asset pipeline configuration that tries to be smart about z-indexes and intelligently reduce them?

Seems like a smart thing to do, but in this case, I'd like to disable the functionality...

Comment: Assets pipeline doesn't use compass and it's weird you get that because the sass-rails is only meant to convert the scss code to css and process things like asset-url(), image-url(), and font-url() as listed here https://github.com/rails/sass-rails

Comment: Try adding an id to that element and see if it then works.  If so, then at least you know some other style is overwriting it with another call to !important after it.  I would then adjust the order at which these assets are called and move it further down the list of precompilation.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer to this (old) problem, I'm not even sure that webpacker was around at the time, but it may help others who find this post.

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1663

In my case, Webpacker was using cssnano to optimize the compiled and minimized CSS. One of these optimizations reduces the z-index to the minimum possible values to make all your bundled CSS still work. This causes problems if you're still also using the asset pipeline for other CSS.

The fix was adding 
`environment.plugins.get('OptimizeCSSAssets').options.cssProcessorOptions.safe = true`
to `config/webpack/production.js`.